# Python pandas How to pick up certain values by internal numbering?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Answers  all_answers  Score
0       0.0            0     72
1       0.0            0     73
2       0.0            0     74
3       1.0            1      1
4      -1.0            1      2
5       1.0            1      3
6      -1.0            1      4
7       1.0            1      5
8       0.0            0      1
9       0.0            0      2
10     -1.0            1      1
11      0.0            0      1
12      0.0            0      2
13      1.0            1      1
14      0.0            0      1
15      0.0            0      2
16      1.0            1      1
```

The first column is a signal that the sign has changed in the calculation flow

The second one is I just removed the minus from the first one

The third is an internal account for the second column - how much was one and how much was zero

I want to add a fourth column to it that would show me only those units that went in a row for example 5 times while observing the sign of the first column.

To get something like this

```
    Answers  all_answers  Score  New
0       0.0            0     72    0
1       0.0            0     73    0
2       0.0            0     74    0
3       1.0            1      1    1
4      -1.0            1      2   -1
5       1.0            1      3    1
6      -1.0            1      4   -1
7       1.0            1      5    1
8       0.0            0      1    0
9       0.0            0      2    0
10     -1.0            1      1    0
11      0.0            0      1    0
12      0.0            0      2    0
13      1.0            1      1    0
14      0.0            0      1    0
15      0.0            0      2    0
16      1.0            1      1    0
17      0.0            0      1    0
```

Is it possible to do this by Pandas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# group by consecutive 0/1
g = df['all_answers'].ne(df['all_answers'].shift()).cumsum()

# get size of each group and compare to threshold
m = df.groupby(g)['all_answers'].transform('size').ge(5)

# mask small groups
df['New'] = df['Answers'].where(m, 0)
```

Output:

```
    Answers  all_answers  Score  New
0       0.0            0     72  0.0
1       0.0            0     73  0.0
2       0.0            0     74  0.0
3       1.0            1      1  1.0
4      -1.0            1      2 -1.0
5       1.0            1      3  1.0
6      -1.0            1      4 -1.0
7       1.0            1      5  1.0
8       0.0            0      1  0.0
9       0.0            0      2  0.0
10     -1.0            1      1  0.0
11      0.0            0      1  0.0
12      0.0            0      2  0.0
13      1.0            1      1  0.0
14      0.0            0      1  0.0
15      0.0            0      2  0.0
16      1.0            1      1  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster way (with `regex`):

```
import pandas as pd
import re


def repl5(m):
    return '5' * len(m.group())


s = df['all_answers'].astype(str).str.cat()

d = re.sub('(?:1{5,})', repl5, s)

d = [x=='5' for x in list(d)]

df['New'] = df['Answers'].where(d, 0.0)
df
```

Output:

```
    Answers  all_answers  Score  New
0       0.0            0     72  0.0
1       0.0            0     73  0.0
2       0.0            0     74  0.0
3       1.0            1      1  1.0
4      -1.0            1      2 -1.0
5       1.0            1      3  1.0
6      -1.0            1      4 -1.0
7       1.0            1      5  1.0
8       0.0            0      1  0.0
9       0.0            0      2  0.0
10     -1.0            1      1  0.0
11      0.0            0      1  0.0
12      0.0            0      2  0.0
13      1.0            1      1  0.0
14      0.0            0      1  0.0
15      0.0            0      2  0.0
16      1.0            1      1  0.0
```

Comment: It's not faster on large datasets, for instance on ~100k rows it's 10x slower than the transform approach ;)

Comment: @mozway I don't think so! It's 2x faster on ~170K rows than your approach. ;)

Comment: Not sure how you tested, I got >100ms vs 9ms. Benchmarking should always be done with care anyway before making any claim as it can be highly susceptible to the data. ;)

Comment: Tested again on 17 and 170k (`df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)`): yours `1.27 ms ± 70.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)` and `229 ms ± 33.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`, mine: `4.96 ms ± 2.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` and `32 ms ± 2.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`.

Comment: @mozway Yours: `2876624 function calls (2776542 primitive calls) in 2.214 seconds` mine: `1474032 function calls (1423983 primitive calls) in 1.193 seconds`

Comment: That doesn't explain how you tested (I used `timeit`). Anyway, as said hard to conclude so your "faster way" is for sure not a generality ;)

Comment: @mozway Hmm, I think maybe there is a relationship between sequences of `1{5,}`  in `all_answers` and time for my approach.